# Storing user data using jwt

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo-client

I am fetching user data from the graphql backend through the apollo client. My goal is to keep the user logged in, so I signed jwt token with all user data, passed it to localStorage(only the token), decoded it, and passed all values to redux-store.

```
       UserModel:
 userSchema.methods.createJWT = function (payload) {
      return jwt.sign({ ...payload }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: '1d',
      });
    };
```

userLogin:

```
      await user.save();
      return {
        ...user._doc,
        id: user._id,
        token: user.createJWT(user._doc),
}
```

reduxSlice

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    userInfo: localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')
      ? jwtDecode(localStorage.getItem('jwtToken'))
      : null,
  },  
  reducers: {
    loginUser: (state, action) => {
      localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', action.payload.token);
      state.userInfo = action.payload;
    },
```

I am wondering if this is ok that the token is holding too much info
like:

```
{
  "_id": "62a9ee3878c4979fedb471c5",
  "username": "***",
  "email": "***",
  "password": "$2a$12$hN2lfCtEbqOOFSlHpapyfuxYAHdEGUYKeHY4BMK1YvYOtSG7zHwcS",
  "isAdmin": false,
  "shippingAddress": [],
  "createdAt": "2022-06-15T14:35:36.877Z",
  "updatedAt": "2022-06-16T09:04:59.367Z",
  "__v": 0,
  "firstName": "***",
  "lastName": "***",
  "shoeSize": 4,
  "iat": 1655371413,
  "exp": 1655457813
}
```

There is another effective way to save user data and keep him logged in?

Comment: You should **never** store the password inside the JWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not recommended (actually very dangerous) to return all information with the jwt token especially password. I think userId is enough!
But you can also return username, firstName, lastName, etc.
But in some cases even returning email address is not a good approach for some user privacy reasons.

I mean by that you have only to get the userId once there is a user and the credentials are correct, then :

```js
const userToken = {
  userId: user._id,
  username: user.username,
};
 
return {
  user,
  token: user.createJWT(userData)
};
```

Now after signing the jwt token , you can set whatever data from user inside some redux state or even react context , (choose your favorite) , but DON'T set any password in the localStorage.

Update: at the end you should store the user from the payload like this :

```js
state.userInfo = action.payload.user;
```

Btw you should check the localStorage only to get the token and verify it , then based on userId you need to fetch the user and store it, here is an example :

```js
  const getUser = React.useCallback(async (userId) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/auth/login', {userId}, {
        credentials: 'include',
        withCredentials: true
      });
      const { accessToken, user } = res.data;
      setState((currentState: IState) => ({
        ...currentState,
        user,
        loading: false,
        isAuth: !!accessToken,
        accessToken
      }));
    } catch (err) {
      setState((currentState: IState) => ({
        ...currentState,
        user: null,
        loading: false,
        isAuth: false,
        accessToken: ''
      }));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser(userId);
  }, [getUser]);

  useEffect(() => {
  const jwtToken = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
    if (jwtToken && jwt_decode(jwtToken)) {
      const { exp } = jwt_decode(jwtToken);
      const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
      if (exp < currentTime) {
        getUserById(userId);
      }
    }
  }, [getUser]);
```

Comment: Ty for the reply! so I did removed password and email from jwt. Now lets say I want to get user email in the client. it is not accessable since there is no email in localstorage. I store username,firstname,lastname in token and the token is passed through redux store so I feel kinda stuck because I can't access that user data.

Comment: you don't need to get all user info from localStorage since every needed data are in user state , in addition i prefer to store the required data inside http only cookie instead of localStorage! anyway localStorage is only needed to see whether user has been logged in or not and if YES then you'll be able to get the userId , but getting the required data should mainly come from user state form Redux or any state management!

Comment: @עמיתשוקרון i updated the code snippet , just take a look at my answer again

Comment: Really appreciate the help and sorry that I am bothering but I do set the data like you just said(state.userInfo = action.payload.user;), the main problem is that when I refresh the data is dissappear, to fix this I just need to store the data through local storage but then we are getting to the same problem that it is not recomended to put that data insidde there (like email password shipping address)

Comment: Oh wait , i see now what you mean, actually the right way to do that is not with storing required data inside the localStorage, but in the initial fetch you have to check the local storage whether user has a token and not expires , then based on userId comes from localStorage you need to fetch the user and store user data inside Redux state @עמיתשוקרון

Comment: I updated my answer again , please take a look @עמיתשוקרון